# Python (LaTeX) - Do I have to use %g formatting, or can I create nice equations with F-string?

Tags: python, latex, f-string

I would like to use F-string because it's much cleaner, but I'm not sure how to mix strings with integers inside curly brackets (maybe it's not possible).

I know you can use double `{{x + 3}}` but I want to use `x` as a variable.
Till now I used `%g` which works great as you can see in the picture.

Is it possible to use F-string and mix **int** with **str** inside curly brackets?

```
x = 7
y = -2
z = 5
answer = -y - (x + 8) // z

display(Math(f"{y} - \\frac{x + 8}{z} = {answer}")) # How to turn + 8 to string? and have the same results as %g

display(Math("%g - \\frac{%g + 8}{%g} = %g" %(y,x,z,answer))) # Works great
```

[image: results]

Comment: `display(Math(f"{y} - \\frac{{{x} + 8}}{{{z}}} = {answer}"))`?